# upsert a field in a subdocument in an array by index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following MongoDB structure

```
{
  _id : ...,
  other_stuff ... ,
  my_array : [
    { title: ...., body: ...., email: .... },
    { title: ...., body: ...., email: .... },
    { title: ...., body: ...., email: .... }
  ]
}
```

I need to update/or insert (if not existent) a field called "click_number" in the subdocument within the "my_array" field. If the "click_number" field is not existent, insert the field and set it to 1; if existent, increment it by 1.

First of all, I don't know how to update an array element by its index, and secondly, I do not know how to do update or insert depending on the existence of the field. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `update` command on your collection as follows (example):

```
db.collection.update(
    { "my_array.title" : "title_one" },
    { $inc : { "my_array.$.click_number" : 1 } }
);
```

*What just happened?*

On the first parameter of `update` you define a `query` to match documents you wish to update. We search for a property named `title` inside the array called `my_array`. You could match against `body` or `email` of course by modifying the dot notation to: `"my_array.email"`.

The second parameter defines the update, the modification to apply. We have a `$inc` operator to increment fields, which we use in this statement. The `query` selects a document with the matched array element. You can reach for this matched array item with the `$` notation. The `"my_array.$"` selects the matched array element, which has a `title`, `email` and `body`. If you try to give value to a non existing field, MongoDB will do it for you. If the field does not exist, `$inc` sets the field to the specified amount. The `$inc` operator accepts positive and negative incremental amounts.

[Learn more about the update command.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)

Another example:

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id : "john", "my_array.email" : "email" },
    { $inc : { "my_array.$.click_number" : 1 } }
);
```

Comment: This is one of the most thoroughly explained answers I've ever seen for meteor. The way you explained this is awesome! Didn't even solve my problem but thanks anyway!