# How to update unique field values to change sort order in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I use Mongoose to store documents and have the following field for sorting them:

```
index: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true},
```

Now suppose I need to rearrange the order.  I have a list that contains elements with two fields - document _id and new index. But here is the problem - if I start changing them one by one, I will get a non-unique index exception. What is a general solution for this problem? Can I change two values at the same time so that I do not cause an exception? How does it work in SQL databases?

Comment: Why not create a new collection, populate it with the reordrered documents, then delete the old collection and rename the new one ?

Comment: Does `index` have to be unique? Sort order doesn't typically rise to the database consistency level.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, probably I should not make unique on the database level.

Comment: @Xodrow, Actually from performance point of view, changing a filed in MongoDB would probably be about the same operation as replacing the whole document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upsert a field in a subdocument in an array by index in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929112/upsert-a-field-in-a-subdocument-in-an-array-by-index-in-mongodb)